Given that, $|z_1 + z_2| = 20 \quad \text{and} \quad |z_1^2 + z_2^2| = 16 $ Evaluate difference of minimum and maximum value of$|z_1^3 + z_2^3|$
Question:
Given that,
$$|z_1 + z_2| = 20 \quad \text{and} \quad |z_1^2 + z_2^2| = 16
$$
Given these conditions, we need to find the difference between the maximum and minimum values of $|z_1^3 + z_2^3|$.
I undersdand this problem requires careful manipulation of complex numbers. But i couldn't manipulate it to a reasonable extent.
*
We're asked to find the difference between the maximum and minimum values of $|z_1^3 + z_2^3|$. Using De Moivre's theorem, we have:
Given hint in the answer key:
To find the extreme values, we differentiate with respect to $\theta_1 - \theta_2$, equate it to zero, and solve for $\theta_1 - \theta_2$. We then substitute this value back to get the maximum and minimum values of $|z_1^3 + z_2^3|$.
This seems way lengthy and unreasonable, is there any elegant or better approach than this?

$|z_1 + z_2| = 20$ does not translate to $r_1 + r_2 = 20$, and $|z_1^2 + z_2^2| = 16$ does not translate to $r_1^2 + r_2^2 = 16$.

Hint: WLOG $ \theta_1 = 0 $.

This is a very useful simplification, but even without this, using single-variable differential calculus to solve an optimization problem is about as simple and straightforward as it gets.

(The idea similar as in John Bentin's answer .)
With $a=z_1 + z_2$ and $b = z_1^2 + z_2^2$ is
$$
 z_1^3 + z_2^3 = -\frac 12 a (a^2 - 3b)
$$
and therefore
$$
 |z_1^3 + z_2^3| = \frac 12 |a| \cdot |a^2 - 3b| = 10 |a^2 -3b| \\
 \begin{cases}
\le 10 (|a|^2 + 3|b|) = 4480 \\
\ge 10 (|a|^2 - 3|b|) = 3520
\end{cases}
$$
by the triangle inequality. The bounds are sharp:

The upper bound is attained if $a^2/b$ is a negative real number, e.g. for $(a,b) = (20, -16)$.
The lower bound is attained if $a^2/b$ is a positive real number, e.g. for $(a, b) = (20, 16)$.

Both cases are possible because the system
$$z_1+z_2=a, z_1^2+z_2^2=b$$
has solutions for any pair $(a, b)$ of complex numbers.
Therefore the desired difference is $4480-3520 = 960$.

$$|z_1+z_2|=20$$
$$|z_1^2+z_2^2|+2|z_1z_2|\ge|z_1^2+z_2^2+2z_1z_2|\ge2|z_1z_2|-|z_1^2+z_2^2|$$
$$208\ge|z_1z_2|\ge192$$
Now,
$$|(z_1+z_2)(z_1^2+z_2^2)|+|z_1z_2||z_1+z_2|\ge |(z_1+z_2)(z_1^2+z_2^2)-z_1z_2(z_1+z_2)|\ge |z_1z_2||z_1+z_2|-|(z_1+z_2)(z_1^2+z_2^2)|$$
$$\implies 20×16+208×20\ge|z_1^3+z_2^3|\ge20×192-20×16$$

You still have to show that the bounds are sharp.

From the given conditions, we may write
$z_1+z_2:=20\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\theta}$ and  $z_1^2+z_2^2:=16\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}$
for some angles $\theta$ and $\phi$. It follows that $$z:=z_1^3+z_2^3=\tfrac12(z_1+z_2)[(3(z_1^2+z_2^2)-(z_1+z_2)^2]=160(3\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(\theta+\phi)}-25\mathrm e^{3\mathrm i\theta}).$$ Now $|z|$ is extremal when $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(\theta+\phi)}=\pm\mathrm e^{3\mathrm i\theta}$, namely when
$\phi\equiv2\theta\;(\!\!\!\!\mod\!\pi).$ To see that this is possible, let us write $w:=z_2/z_1$. Then we need
$$\frac{(z_1+z_2)^2}{z_1^2+z_2^2}=\frac{(1+w)^2}{1+w^2}=\pm25.$$
This is indeed possible, because the two quadratic equations in $w$ that this represents each have (two complex) solutions.
Accordingly, the difference between the extrema of $|z|$ is $160(28-22)=960$.

You still have to show that $ e^{ i(\theta+\phi)}=\pm e^{3 i\theta}$ can be achieved with complex numbers $z_1, z_2$.

You're right, @MartinR. I will edit or withdraw my answer.

One can use that the system $z_1+z_2=a, z_1^2+z_2^2=b$ is solvable for any pair $a, b$.

Please don't withdraw your answer : it is almost correct. I am going to give one which is very similar to yours but without angles.

@MartinR : I hope that my edit fills the gap OK.

@JohnBentin: It surely does (already voted :)

You can go through the algebra:
Solving simultaneously:
$$(z_1+z_2)\overline{(z_1+z_2)}=400\\(z_1^2+z_2^2)\overline{(z_1^2+z_2^2)}=256$$
We get eight solutions for $(z_1,z_2):$
$$(\mp 10 \mp 6\sqrt{3}i,  \mp10 \mp6\sqrt{3}i),(\mp 10 \mp 2\sqrt{23}i,  \mp10 \mp\sqrt{23}i),$$
Computing $$|z_1^3+z_2^3|$$ in each case, we have $$4480 \text{ or } 3520.$$
The difference (subtracting the lesser value from the greater) yields:
$$4480-3520=960.$$
UPDATE
Thank you for the helpful comments.  You are right.  These are not the complete set of solutions.  Rather these are the solutions to the equations
$$z_1+z_2 = \mp 20\\z_1^2+z_2^2=\mp 16$$
The full set of solutions is found, as noted by @diracdeltafunk, by multiplying each of $z_1$ and $z_2$ by a complex number on the unit circle:  $e^{i\vartheta}$
If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are the "solutions" found above, the complete set of solutions are:
$$z_1^\star = e^{i\vartheta}z_1 \text{ and } z_2^\star = e^{i\vartheta}z_2 $$ where $$\vartheta \in [0,2\pi)$$

Maybe I'm missing something: if we multiply $z_1$ and $z_2$ by $e^{it}$ (for any real number $t$), it should not change the value of $\lvert z_1^n + z_2^n \rvert$ (for all positive integers $n$). Since there is a nonzero solution, shouldn't this produce infinitely many solutions?

How do you find these solutions ? By using a CAS, but with which instructions ? How can you be sure there are none others ?

Mathematica does seem to claim that this is the complete list of solutions, but I think it is wrong. I've posted about this potential bug here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/301763/2282

Let us take as new variables

$r_1$, the modulus of $z_1$

$i \omega = \tfrac{z_2}{z_1}$.


The two conditions become :
$$\begin{cases}r_1 |1+i \omega|&=&20\\r_1^2 |1 - \omega^2|&=&16\end{cases}$$
Besides, the final expression to be "bracketed" between its extreme values is
$$S=r_1^3 |1-i \omega^3|$$
Let us use identity (the same as @John Bentin) :
$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=\frac12(a+b)(3(a^2+b^2)-(a+b)^2)$$
$$1+(i \omega)^3 = \tfrac12 (1+i \omega)\left(3 (1- \omega^2)-(1+i \omega)^2\right)$$
If we multiply by $r_1^3$ the LHS and the RHS, we get :
$$r_1^3(1-i \omega^3) = \tfrac12 \underbrace{r_1(1+i \omega)}_u \left(\underbrace{3 r_1^2(1- \omega^2)}_v-\underbrace{(r_1(1+i \omega))^2}_w\right)$$
Taking the modulus :
$$|S|=\underbrace{\tfrac12 |u|}_{=10} |v-w|$$
therefore with

minimal value $10$ times the absolute value of $|v|-|w|$, i.e., $10 \times |48-400|=3520$,

maximal value $10$ times $|v|+|w|$, i.e., $10 \times |48+400|= 4480$.


The gap between these extreme values is $960$.
